# Error converting data type varchar to numeric value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a problem on executing this query.

```
select 
CASE when (c.Rate=0.00) then a.Item else cast('N/A' AS DECIMAL(5,2))  end 
from item a join rate_m c on a.item=c.item where  a.item='0781718171'
```

When I execute this query I got an error as,

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 4
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

and I tried to cast them as above but not successful. Please help me on this and the column `c.rate` is created as `decimal(5,2)`.

I need output as N/A if `c.rate is > 0.00`

Answer (score 0):

You cant `CAST` `VARCHAR` value to `DECIMAL`, but you can `CAST` `DECIMAL` value to `VARCHAR`.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN c.Rate>0.00 THEN 'N/A' ELSE CAST(a.Item AS VARCHAR) END 
FROM item a 
JOIN rate_m c ON a.item=c.item 
WHERE  a.item='0781718171'
```